# if condition not working when run from crontab

Tags: shell, cron

my requirement is if "Date" matches with the list of dates present in "file.txt", then it should say sucess "Date has matched".

```
#!/bin/bash

Date="Jun212018"

for i in `cat /home/file.txt`
do

if [ $i == $VT ]
then
echo "Date has Matched"
fi

done
```

Comment: What's `"$VT"` supposed to be?

Comment: How are you executing this from `cron`? Are expecting `Date has Matched` to be produced for each date in `file.txt` that matches? What happens when you try to run this? What is `$VT`?

Comment: what's the link to crontab ?

Comment: WHat is $VT, it should be $Date ?

Comment: #!/bin/bash

Date="Jun212018"

for i in `cat /home/file.txt`
do

if [ $i == $Date ]
then
echo "Date has Matched"
fi

done

Comment: ^^ Update your question. Don't put updates in comments as they're much harder to read or even find

Comment: "Update your question" does not mean "Open a new question" ...

Comment: click on [edit] and add more information to your question, your script cannot work in its actual form. What contains `/home/file.txt` (btw $() is to be prefered above `` as command substitution). What is the variable $VT ? please put `""` around your variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your script leaves `VT` undefined (unless it's set in the environment, but that leaves `Date` unused).

A simpler script:

```
#!/bin/sh

if grep -q -Fx 'Jun212018' /home/file.txt; then
    echo 'Date has Matched'
fi
```

This prints the string if the date `Jun212018` matches exactly on a single line in the file.

---

From comments below, it seem this is what you want to be doing:

```
#!/bin/sh

today=$( date +%b%d%Y )

if grep -q -Fx "$today" /home/file.txt; then
    echo 'date has matched' >/home/otherfile
fi
```

Comment: i tried, this works fine from command line, but doesn't work from crontab

Comment: if grep -q -Fx 'Jun212018' /home/file.txt; then
    touch file1.txt
fi

Comment: if grep -q -Fx 'Jun212018' /home/file.txt; then                                                                
    touch file1.txt
fi

Comment: @user296431 So, what happens when you run from `cron`?  Also, what is the point of the code you posted in your later comments?  What is it that you want to say/do?

Comment: my requirement is if today's date matched with a list of dates present in a file, it should say "Date has matched" and create a file with the data as "date has matched" . this script is working fine from command line, but when run from cron, if condition is not working, file is not getting created..

Comment: @user296431 Your script does not use today's date, it uses a fixed string. It also does not put any data into any file, so I find it hard to believe that your script works.

Comment: this is not working when ran from cron...but workinf fine from command line..

Comment: sure it's working because the fixed string IS todays date. But tomorrow it will not work anymore. Also in your script you just use "echo". Where do you think the output will appear?

Comment: @user296431 What does "not working" mean? Do you get error messages? I can't see your screen from where I'm sitting, you know...